# Command `run-android` unrecognized after installing any additional package in React Native project

Tags: android, node.js, windows, react-native, npm

I started working on a React Native project, everything was going very well. I was able to run my project on an android emulator, but then I wanted to add some other packages in my react native project.
I tried to run my project once again on android emulator and I got error `Command run-android unrecognized. Make sure that you have run npm install and that you are inside a react-native project.`
I tried to create a new project, and add any package just to see if it will work, and I got the same error.

Got on my Linux machine and tried the same thing, and I didn't get any errors, but on Windows it won't work.

I'm working on Windows 10 -.-
node version : 8.0.0
react-native : 0.44.2

Comment: Not to sound belittling, just to make sure: Are you sure you actually are in the folder? Note that when you create a project with `react-native init App` you'll have to `cd App`. If you are sure, can you post the output of `dir`?

Comment: Ofc I was in a directory, as I was saying, I was working on the project :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this exact same problem. This is most likely caused by after running `npm install` most of the library folders inside the `node_modules` become empty or gone. I'm not really sure whether this problems caused by npm or react-native itself (since both had release a new version recently).

A 'bruteforce' method to resolve this is copy `node_modules` folder from a fresh react-native app into your current project. cheers~

**EDIT**

I'm sorry if I caused a misleading. This problem occur because you use 2 differents package manager (in my case npm and yarn). If you install yarn, `react-native-cli` will automatically use yarn and populate a yarn package (which will make your package.json empty). So if you install a package via npm, it will generate empty node_modules folder (plus your new package). Try install the package using yarn (`yarn add package-name`), it works for me.

Comment: You my friend are a genius. Thank you soo soo much :D.
Installing with yarn really helped

Comment: you just saved my day